# How do you return a boolean value for a regexp scan of an integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, integer

I'm looking through my object attributes for culprits that are not :

```
^[1-3]{3}$
```

What is the method used to scan integers for regexp?

Comment: Why don't you convert integer to string and scan string?

Comment: @Bohdan, that doesn't return a boolean value though so I wouldn't be able to detect whether it worked or not.. at least i don't think i could.

Comment: mm I'm not sure if I get everything right but `"1234"[/^[1-3]{3}$/]` returns `nil` which is `false` and `"123"[/^[1-3]{3}$/]` returns `"123"` which is `true` Is is sth similar to what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some examples:

```
124.to_s.match(/^[1-3]{3}$/)
=> nil
123.to_s.match(/^[1-3]{3}$/)
=>#<MatchData "123">
```

Since `nil` is considered as `false`, you have your boolean.

Ex:

```
 "no yo" if 124.to_s.match(/^[1-3]{3}$/)
 => nil
 "yo!" if 123.to_s.match(/^[1-3]{3}$/)
 => "yo!"
```

Comment: Don't do this if you're serializing your cache with Marshal – it can't dump MatchData and will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

You may use also one of the following:

```
def is_pure_integer?(i)
  i.to_i.to_s == i.to_s
end
```

or

`'132' =~ /^\d+$/ ? true : false`